FunT Ton Language send to multiple addresses
I`m writing FunC ton language. Here is my code in recv_internal:
    int amount = 10004000;

    slice dis_address1 = "0QCqKALVHGWllnc90l3oQ0yn6j0bJ2vyQp-IV76Dxm9TnWdL"a;

    sum = sum + amount;

    var msg = begin_cell()
        .store_uint(0x18, 6)
        .store_slice(dis_address1)
        .store_coins(amount)
        .store_uint(0, 107)
        .end_cell();
    send_raw_message(msg, 1);

    dis_address1 = "UQCHuLFRfhnMFHPHnmWmzcuIRa14I9x-cTAwUHPjQZPGVUkV"a;
    var msg = begin_cell()
        .store_uint(0x18, 6)
        .store_slice(dis_address1)
        .store_coins(amount)
        .store_uint(0, 107)
        .end_cell();
    send_raw_message(msg, 1);

Problem is that when I call send_raw_message function just once,
It works fine. But when I call this code completely(with two addresses),it does not works.
My contract has enough balance(0.0892 TON):
https://testnet.tonscan.org/address/EQDPCpEaVLsuYMwcA7jQq-XXOUdKTE0-yIRlGZ6YQKRtVjgF
Any help?
Thanks
